# How to get CPU features/extfeatures items in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, cpu

In my cocoa app, I'm trying to use sysctl to display my cpu features/extfeatures items.

An example:

If I do...

```
// Set CPU Instructions

- (void)setInstructions
{
    size_t size;
    int32_t sse;
    sysctlbyname("hw.optional.sse", &sse, &size, nil, 0);
    self.Instructions.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sse];
}
```

I will obtain "1" ("0" for not supported, "1" for supported).

But I would convert this decimal number with string "SSE". How can I do that?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I found a way which it is working fine but I don't feel it is a proper way.

```
if (sse == 1)
 self.Instructions.stringValue = @"SSE";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found a better way to obtain what I want

```
NSString *sse, *sse2, *sse3;
    uint64_t cpuid_feature_sse = CPUID_FEATURE_SSE;
    sse = @"";
        switch (cpuid_feature_sse) {
            case CPUID_FEATURE_SSE:
            sse = @"SSE";
                break;
        }
    uint64_t cpuid_feature_sse2 = CPUID_FEATURE_SSE2;
    sse2 = @"";
    switch (cpuid_feature_sse2) {
        case CPUID_FEATURE_SSE2:
            sse2 = @"SSE2";
            break;
    }
    uint64_t cpuid_feature_sse3 = CPUID_FEATURE_SSE3;
    sse3 = @"";
    switch (cpuid_feature_sse3) {
        case CPUID_FEATURE_SSE3:
            sse3 = @"SSE3";
            break;
    }
    self.Instructions.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", sse, sse2, sse3];
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn4W7.png)

Please, tell me if you all agree with this and/or if there's a more simple and proper way to do it.

Cdt

Comment: Hum... I think it is not a right way. If I add CPUID_FEATURE_SSE4_2, the result will show SSE4.2, even if my CPU does not support it.  :(